# Celery worker not running

Tags: python, celery

Below tis the traceback when I run

```
celery -A tasks worker -l info
```

I am unable to figure out whats wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/celery", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('celery==3.1.7', 'console_scripts', 'celery')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/__main__.py", line 30, in main
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 80, in main
    cmd.execute_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/celery.py", line 723, in execute_from_commandline
    super(CeleryCommand, self).execute_from_commandline(argv)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 301, in execute_from_commandline
    argv = self.setup_app_from_commandline(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 431, in setup_app_from_commandline
    self.app = self.find_app(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/bin/base.py", line 451, in find_app
    return find_app(app, symbol_by_name=self.symbol_by_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/celery/app/utils.py", line 233, in find_app
    found = sym.celery
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'celery'
```

The most frustrating part is it worked without errors last night.

Comment: Most likely a version conflict or broken installation. Try do a clean reinstall. If that doesn't solve the issue use pdb breakpoints in the code to see what "sym" variable contains there.

Comment: Are you sure the app is called tasks?

Answer (score 0):

Check your PYTHONPATH for old celery code.

I had exactly the same fault at the same line in utils.py (with celery 3.1.10).

The reason turned out to be that I had some old directories contain experiments from earlier versions of Celery and these were being picked up via the PYTHONPATH. I removed the old directories from the PYTHONPATH and everything started working.

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is your files tree:

APP

--> MyProject

-----> celery.py

--> run_celery.py

Where run_celery.py includes this line:

```
celery -A tasks worker -l info
```

From one level upper than the celery.py file.

run_celery.py should be on the same level as MyProject